# Não consigo enviar dados do formulário com AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Eu estou com um problema alguns dias, que com teste e pesquisa não estou conseguindo resolver. Meu problema persiste em um certo formulário enviar os dados via AJAX para o PHP tratar e enviar um e-mail, até ai funciona sem maiores problemas. O adicional é, ao enviar os dados aparecer uma mensagem no lugar no formulário o que também consigo fazer.

O problema é: eu não consigo mostrar a mensagem e enviar os dados por e-mail. É como se ele ou fizesse uma coisa ou outra. Vai os código principal abaixo:

**AJAX**

```
$("#f_pre_cadastro").submit(function(e) {       

    var form_data = $(this).serialize();                    // Pega os dados do FORM
    var form_url = $(this).attr("action");                  // Pega o ACTION
    var form_method = $(this).attr("method").toUpperCase(); // POST ou GET

    $.ajax({
            url: form_url, 
            type: form_method,      
            data: form_data,     
            cache: false,                                   // força as páginas solicitadas a não serem armazenada em cache         
            success:  function(returnhtml){   
                if(returnhtml){
                    $("form").css({"display": "none"});
                    $('h2').html('Parabéns!'); 
                    $('p').html('Seus dados foram enviados com sucesso! <br> Aguarde nosso retorno por e-mail.');   
                }else{
                    window.alert('Erro!');
                }   
            }

    }); 

    //e.preventDefault();   
    //e.stopPropagation();
    return false;

});
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST["btnEnviar"]) && $_POST["nome_f"] != '' && isset($_POST["email_f"]) && $_POST["email_f"] != ''){

        $nome_f     = isset($_POST["nome_f"]) ? ucwords_improved(anti_injection($_POST["nome_f"])) : '';
        $email_f    = isset($_POST["email_f"]) ? anti_injection($_POST["email_f"]) : '';
        $whatsapp   = isset($_POST["whatsapp_f"]) ? anti_injection($_POST["whatsapp_f"]) : '';
        $empresa    = isset($_POST["empresa_f"]) ? anti_injection($_POST["empresa_f"]) : '';
        $cpfCnpj    = isset($_POST["cpfCnpj_f"]) ? anti_injection($_POST["cpfCnpj_f"]) : '';
        $finalidade = isset($_POST["finalidade_f"]) ? anti_injection($_POST["finalidade_f"]) : '';

        //envia email de solicitação de cadastro
        $email_destinatario    = 'meuemail@mail.com.br';
        $subject   = 'Site - Novo Cadastro: ' . $nome_f;

        $body = '
        <p style="margin:10px 0; line-height:160%">
        <br>Olá, Moisés !
        <br><br>Você recebeu um novo e-mail de solicitação de cadastro!
        <br><br>Nome: ' . $nome_f . '
        <br><br>E-mail: ' . $email_f . '
        <br><br>WhatsApp: ' . $whatsapp . '
        <br><br>Empresa: ' . $empresa . '
        <br><br>CPF/CNPJ: ' . $cpfCnpj . '
        <br><br>Finalidade do Cadastro: ' . $finalidade . '        
        </p>';      


        $envioEmailSolicitacao = sendMail($nome_f, 'teste@teste.com', $email_f, $email_destinatario, $subject, $body);

        if($envioEmailSolicitacao){
            $alerta   = 'Seus dados foram enviados com sucesso!';                          
        }else{
            $alerta   = 'Erro ao enviar e-mail. Tente novamente!';
        }

    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="section-block-parallax" id="comece-ja" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $config_base_path; ?>/img/cadastro.jpg);">
    <!-- Gradient Overlay START -->
    <div class="gradient-overlay"></div>
    <!-- Gradient Overlay END -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="section-heading center-holder white-color wow fadeInDown animated">
            <h2>Cadastre-se</h2>
            <p>Preencha o formulário abaixo para nossa equipe fazer uma pré-análise dos seus dados. <br> Se seu cadastro for aceito, você receberá um link por e-mail para prosseguir.</p>
            <div class="section-heading-line"></div>
        </div>      
        <div class="center-holder wow fadeInUp animated mt-50" data-wow-delay=".3s">
            <form id="f_pre_cadastro" class="comment-form" method="post" action="<?php echo selfURL(); ?>">
                <?php
                if(isset($alerta)){
                    echo '<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-4 center-block"><p style="margin:0 0 20px 0; clear:both !important; color:#FFF"><strong>'. $alerta. '</strong></p></div></div> <script>window.alert("'. $alerta. '");</script>';
                }
                ?>  
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 center-block">
                        <label for="f_nome">Seu nome</label> 
                        <input name="nome_f" id="f_nome" value="" required> <!-- 'f' é referente a finalidade do uso -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 center-block">
                        <label for="f_email">Seu e-mail</label>
                        <div class="alerta">
                            <input name="email_f" id="f_email" type="email" value="" maxlength="100" required>
                            <p class="msg_alerta" id="msg_email_alerta"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 center-block">
                        <label for="f_whatsapp">Seu WhatsApp</label>
                        <div class="alerta">
                            <input name="whatsapp_f" id="f_whatsapp" type="" value="" maxlength="100" required>                         
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 center-block">
                        <label for="f_empresa">Empresa</label>
                        <div class="alerta">
                            <input name="empresa_f" id="f_empresa" type="" value="" maxlength="100" required>                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 center-block">
                        <label for="f_cpfCnpj">CPF/CNPJ</label>
                        <div class="alerta">
                            <input name="cpfCnpj_f" id="f_cpfCnpj" type="" value="" maxlength="100" required>                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 center-block">
                        <label for="f_finalidade">Qual a finalidade do seu cadastro ?</label>
                        <div class="alerta">
                            <textarea style="margin-top: 0;" name="finalidade_f" id="f_finalidade" type="" value="" maxlength="100" required></textarea>                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 center-block">
                        <button type="submit" name="btnEnviar" class="gradient-button button-sm" id="bt_submit">Enviar</button>
                    </div>                          
                </div>                

            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Obs.: Eu estava matutando que o '*return false*' do **AJAX** por desabilitar o 'objetivo' do '*submit*', ele não envie os dados, mas não consegui pensar um logica que faça o envio dos dados por e-mail e mostre a mensagem sem problemas.

Comment: Se corrigiu o problema, poste a solução como resposta, explique o que estava errado e mostre porque a solução resolveu o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Envie utilizando `json_encode`, o seu formulário está sendo enviado, mas a onde você colocou pra mostrar?

um `echo` em `alerta` resolveria, mas recomendo que faça:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#f_pre_cadastro").submit(function(e) {       

    var form_data = $(this).serialize();                    // Pega os dados do FORM
    var form_url = $(this).attr("action");                  // Pega o ACTION
    var form_method = $(this).attr("method").toUpperCase(); // POST ou GET

    $.ajax({
            url: form_url, 
            type: form_method,      
            data: form_data,
            dataType: 'json',  
            cache: false,                                   // força as páginas solicitadas a não serem armazenada em cache         
            success:  function(returnhtml){   
                if(returnhtml.status == 'ok'){
                    $("form").css({"display": "none"});
                    $('h2').html('Parabéns!'); 
                    $('p').html(returnhtml.message);   
                }else if (returnhtml.status == 'fail'){
                    window.alert(returnhtml.message);
                }   
            }

    }); 

    //e.preventDefault();   
    //e.stopPropagation();
    return false;

  });
})
```

No PHP, pra testar eu retirei as validações que vc tinha, basta vc adicionar de novo, ok?

```
    <?php
if(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

  $nome_f = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome_f');
  $email_f = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email_f');
  $whatsapp = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'whatsapp');
  $empresa = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'empresa');
  $cpfCnpj = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cpfCnpj');
  $finalidade = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'finalidade');

  //envia email de solicitação de cadastro
  $email_destinatario    = 'meuemail@mail.com.br';
  $subject   = 'Site - Novo Cadastro: ' . $nome_f;

  $body = '
  <p style="margin:10px 0; line-height:160%">
  <br>Olá, Moisés !
  <br><br>Você recebeu um novo e-mail de solicitação de cadastro!
  <br><br>Nome: ' . $nome_f . '
  <br><br>E-mail: ' . $email_f . '
  <br><br>WhatsApp: ' . $whatsapp . '
  <br><br>Empresa: ' . $empresa . '
  <br><br>CPF/CNPJ: ' . $cpfCnpj . '
  <br><br>Finalidade do Cadastro: ' . $finalidade . '        
  </p>';      


  $envioEmailSolicitacao = sendMail($nome_f, 'teste@teste.com', $email_f, $email_destinatario, $subject, $body);

  if($envioEmailSolicitacao){
    echo json_encode(array(
      'status' => 'ok',
      'message' => 'Seus dados foram enviados com sucesso!'
    ));                          
  }else{
    echo json_encode(array(
      'status' => 'fail',
      'message' => 'Erro ao enviar e-mail. Tente novamente!'
    )); 
  }
```

Comment: Sem sucesso infelizmente. Com sua opção ele nem mostra o formulario para preenchimento dos dados. Tentei verificar algum ; faltando, e até coloquei apos a função json_encode, mas sem retorno. Obrigado

Comment: Eu fiz uma edição, tinha alguns erros

Answer (score -1):

PHP

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST["btnEnviar"]) && $_POST["nome_f"] != '' && isset($_POST["email_f"]) && $_POST["email_f"] != ''){

    $nome_f     = isset($_POST["nome_f"]) ? ucwords_improved(anti_injection($_POST["nome_f"])) : '';
    $email_f    = isset($_POST["email_f"]) ? anti_injection($_POST["email_f"]) : '';
    $whatsapp   = isset($_POST["whatsapp_f"]) ? anti_injection($_POST["whatsapp_f"]) : '';
    $empresa    = isset($_POST["empresa_f"]) ? anti_injection($_POST["empresa_f"]) : '';
    $cpfCnpj    = isset($_POST["cpfCnpj_f"]) ? anti_injection($_POST["cpfCnpj_f"]) : '';
    $finalidade = isset($_POST["finalidade_f"]) ? anti_injection($_POST["finalidade_f"]) : '';

    //envia email de solicitação de cadastro
    $email_destinatario    = 'meuemail@mail.com.br';
    $subject   = 'Site - Novo Cadastro: ' . $nome_f;

    $body = '
    <p style="margin:10px 0; line-height:160%">
    <br>Olá, Moisés !
    <br><br>Você recebeu um novo e-mail de solicitação de cadastro!
    <br><br>Nome: ' . $nome_f . '
    <br><br>E-mail: ' . $email_f . '
    <br><br>WhatsApp: ' . $whatsapp . '
    <br><br>Empresa: ' . $empresa . '
    <br><br>CPF/CNPJ: ' . $cpfCnpj . '
    <br><br>Finalidade do Cadastro: ' . $finalidade . '        
    </p>';      


    $envioEmailSolicitacao = sendMail($nome_f, 'teste@teste.com', $email_f, $email_destinatario, $subject, $body);

    if($envioEmailSolicitacao){
        $alerta   = 'Seus dados foram enviados com sucesso!';

    }else{
        $alerta   = 'Erro ao enviar e-mail. Tente novamente!';

    }
    return $alerta;
    }
?>
```

AJAX

```
$("#f_pre_cadastro").submit(function(e) {       

var form_data = $(this).serialize();                    // Pega os dados do FORM
var form_url = $(this).attr("action");                  // Pega o ACTION
var form_method = $(this).attr("method").toUpperCase(); // POST ou GET

$.ajax({
        url: form_url, 
        type: form_method,      
        data: form_data,     
        cache: false,                                   // força as páginas solicitadas a não serem armazenada em cache         
        success:  function(returnhtml,msg){   
            if(returnhtml){
                $("form").css({"display": "none"});
                $('h2').html('Parabéns!'); 
                $('p').html('Seus dados foram enviados com sucesso! <br> Aguarde nosso retorno por e-mail.');

            }
             alert(msg);
        },
        error: function(){
            return false;

        }

}); 

//e.preventDefault();   
//e.stopPropagation();
return false;
});
```

Tente assim, utilizei o `return` e o echo no PHP para poder prevenir erros, e utilzei também o atributo `error` no `AJAX`

Comment: Obrigado DbaAlone. O seu parcialmente deu certo. Ele enviou o e-mail, mostrou a mensagem estilizada no lugar do form e apos isso ele carrega a pagina. Mostrando a mensagem do echo do PHP e não mais a mensagem estilizada.

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado, pode marcar como concluida? ecaso queira pode retirar o echo, eu fiz mais por precaução, caso o return não funcionasse.

Comment: Então meu amigo, eu fiz suas alterações e entendi parcialmente. Ele mostra a mensagem rapidamente e carrega a pagina não mostra nada, vou te mandar o link da aplicação para vc ter uma noção: https://linkto.bio/

Comment: não consegui verificar o erro, um momento irei alterar a resposta e veja se ajuda

Comment: Verifique este link aonde ele mostra a parte de timeout, aonde o js espera um determinado tempo para continuar.    https://www.gigasystems.com.br/artigo/17/como-definir-o-tempo-de-atraso-em-javascript

Comment: O resultado é o esperado, mas ele não envia o formulário com esse ultimo return false.

Eu estou acompanhando o console na aba de network onde ele mostra a requisição AJAX. O que eu entendi por lá é que com esse ultimo return ele segura o index(linkto.bio), na outra forma quando assim ele envia o form para o e-mail, ele segura por uns instante e envia o mesmo, nesse mesmo momento de instantes é que é mostrado a mensagem.

Em relação ao timeout é que ele depois de um momento vai recarregar a pagina, assim mostrando o form novamente esse não é o requisito, infelizmente.

Answer (score -1):

Tenta usar o jquery para enviar os dados, fica desta forma:

```
$.post(form_url, form_data, function(returnhtml){
    if(returnhtml){
            $("form").css({"display": "none"});
            $('h2').html('Parabéns!'); 
            $('p').html('Seus dados foram enviados com sucesso! <br> Aguarde nosso retorno por e-mail.');   
        }else{
            window.alert('Erro!');
        }   
});
```

Comment: Hmmm Obrigado meu amigo, mas infelizmente não deu certo. O resultado foi ele ter mostrado a mensagem e em uma fração de segundo carregou a pagina(Voltando para a pagina do formulario) enviando assim os dados por e-mail. 

O que eu queria é que ele enviasse os dados por e-mail, mostrasse a mensagem e não carregasse.

Comment: Cara você tem quer dar um retorno na sua página PHP, para que possa aparecer (echo $alerta), e add a função   "e.preventDefault();" no javascript